# Proxy design pattern with IoC

Tags: caching, design-patterns, proxy, inversion-of-control

I am trying to implement proxy design pattern for caching services as below.

```
public interface IProductService
{
   int ProcessOrder(int orderId);
}

public class ProductService : IProductService
{
   public int ProcessOrder(int orderId)
   {
      // implementation
   }
}

public class CachedProductService : IProductService
{
   private IProductService _realService;

   public CachedProductService(IProductService realService)
   {
      _realService = realService;
   }

   public int ProcessOrder(int orderId)
   {
      if (exists-in-cache)
         return from cache
      else
         return _realService.ProcessOrder(orderId);
   }
}
```

How do I to use IoC container (Unity/Autofac) to create real service and cached service objects as I can register *IProductService* to *ProductService* or *CachedProductService* but *CachedProductService* in turn requires a *IProductService* object (*ProductService*) during creation.

I am trying to arrive at something like this:

The application will target *IProductService* and request IoC container for an instance and depending on the configuration of the application (if cache is enabled/disabled), the application will be provided with *ProductService* or *CachedProductService* instance.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a container your graph would look like this:

```
new CachedProductService(
    new ProductService());
```

Here's an example using Simple Injector:

```
container.Register<IProductService, ProductService>();

// Add caching conditionally based on a config switch
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usecaching"] == "true")
    container.RegisterDecorator<IProductService, CachedProductService>();
```

Comment: the type parameters of RegisterDecorator should be swapped.

Comment: @RezaBayat, no, because this is "an example using Simple Injector."